# Converting VB.Net Array to C#

Tags: arrays, vb.net, c#-4.0

Here is a piece of VB.Net code:

```
Dim left As Object = NewLateBinding.LateGet(NewLateBinding.LateGet(sender, Nothing, "PressedLink", New Object(0 - 1) {}, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing), Nothing, "ItemName", New Object(0 - 1) {}, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing)
```

My question is with the:

```
New Object(0 - 1)
```

The online converter converted it to the following C# code:

```
New Object[0 - 1]
```

I did some research on the VB.Net array code and it look like the (0 - 1) is just telling which numbers the index starts and ends on. However, in C# the compiler sees this as a negative 1. I have a feeling that in C# it should be:

```
New Object[2]
```

I just wanted to see if anyone who is more familiar with VB.Net can verify this for me so I know I am doing it correctly or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In VB.NET, when declaring an array you specify the maximum index for each dimension, and these are zero based.  So, `New Object(0) {}` is actually an array with one item.  Because of this, to declare an array with no items, you use `New Object(-1) {}`.  See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wak0wfyt.aspx#BKMK_ZeroLength) for more details.

In your VB.NET code, `New Object(0 - 1)` is the same as `New Object(-1)` - the `0 - 1` part is just zero minus one, or -1, meaning a zero-length array of `Object`.

The C# equivalent is just `new Object[0]`, since in C# you specify the number of elements when declaring an array.

Comment: Ok, I believe this is the answer I am looking for since there isn't anything in the curly brackets right after New Object(0 - 1). Thanks for the help!

Comment: I don't think that having nothing in the curly brackets is particularly relevant to it being a zero-length array.  e.g. in VB.NET, `New Object(4) {}` would give you a 5 element array containing nulls, since no initial values are provided.  The `{}` is just required in VB.NET, even when not initializing the array, while it's optional in C#.  This also shows the possible reason for the style used by the original programmer - `New Object(5 - 1) {}` could be a reminder that VB.NET is a bit odd in how the array dimensions are declared, vs. `New Object(4) {}` - both are 5 element arrays!